# Rolling cumulative product with NAs R

Tags: r

I have the following database (X) that contains monthly stock returns over time. I show the first 12 rows. The stock returns can contain random NAs.

```
Obs. Asset Date Ret
 1 DJ    1997-10-06   NA    
 2 DJ    1997-10-07   NA    
 3 DJ    1997-10-08   -1.13 
 4 DJ    1997-10-09   -0.136
 5 DJ    1997-10-10   NA    
 6 DJ    1997-10-14   NA    
 7 DJ    1997-10-15   NA    
 8 DJ    1997-10-16   -0.225
 9 DJ    1997-10-17   -0.555
10 DJ    1997-10-20   NA    
11 DJ    1997-10-21    0.102
12 DJ    1997-10-22   NA
```

I want to calculate the cumulative return over a 5 day window. So I get a cumulative return from observation 5 on, ignoring NAs. The cumulative return will only be a NA when the returns within the window are also NA.

I tried:

```
Y <- Y %>%
  mutate(product = (as.numeric(rollapply(1 + ret/100, 5, prod,
                                        partial = TRUE, na.rm = TRUE, align = "right"))-1)*100)
```

Which gives an undesired result:

```
> 1 1997-10-06  DJ  NA  0.000000000 
> 2 1997-10-07  DJ  NA  0.000000000
> 3 1997-10-08  DJ  -1.1277917526   -1.127791753
> 4 1997-10-09  DJ  -0.1364864885   -1.262738958
> 5 1997-10-10  DJ  NA  -1.262738958 
> 6 1997-10-14  DJ  NA  -1.262738958
> 7 1997-10-15  DJ  NA  -1.262738958
> 8 1997-10-16  DJ  -0.2250333841   -0.361212732
> 9 1997-10-17  DJ  -0.5545946845   -0.778380045
> 10    1997-10-20  DJ  NA  -0.778380045
> 11    1997-10-21  DJ  0.1022404757    -0.676935389
> 12    1997-10-22  DJ  NA  -0.676935389
```

I want to get NAs before the 5th observation, so row 1-4 are NA. Row 5 computes the cumulative return over row 1-5, Row 6 computes the cumulative return over 2-6 etc.

Reprex:

```
X <- data.frame(Date=c("1997-10-06" ,"1997-10-07", "1997-10-08" ,"1997-10-09", "1997-10-10",
"1997-10-14", "1997-10-15" ,"1997-10-16", "1997-10-17","1997-10-20", "1997-10-21" ,"1997-10-22"),
    ret=c(NA,NA,-1.1277918,-0.1364865, NA , NA ,  NA ,-0.2250334 ,-0.5545947, NA, 0.1022405, NA))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could replace the `NA` with `0` and then use `zoo::rollsum` default behavior:

```
library(zoo)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(ret = zoo::rollsum(tidyr::replace_na(ret, 0), k = 5, na.pad = T, align = "right))

         Date        ret
1  1997-10-06         NA
2  1997-10-07         NA
3  1997-10-08         NA
4  1997-10-09         NA
5  1997-10-10 -1.2642783
6  1997-10-14 -1.2642783
7  1997-10-15 -1.2642783
8  1997-10-16 -0.3615199
9  1997-10-17 -0.7796281
10 1997-10-20 -0.7796281
11 1997-10-21 -0.6773876
12 1997-10-22 -0.6773876
```

Comment: Thank you, kind sir.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code that takes your data, changes all the `NA` in `ret` to `0` and then calculates a rolling 5-period sum using the `RcppRoll` and `tidyverse` packages.

```
# Load libraries
library('RcppRoll')
library('tidyverse')

# Load data
df <- data.frame(Date=c("1997-10-06" ,"1997-10-07", "1997-10-08" ,"1997-10-09", "1997-10-10",
"1997-10-14", "1997-10-15" ,"1997-10-16", "1997-10-17","1997-10-20", "1997-10-21" ,"1997-10-22"),
ret=c(NA,NA,-1.1277918,-0.1364865, NA , NA ,  NA ,-0.2250334 ,-0.5545947, NA, 0.1022405, NA), stringsAsFactors = F)

# Change NA's to Zeros
df[is.na(df[,2]),2] <- 0

# Calculate Rolling Sum
df_new <- df %>% mutate(rollsum = roll_sum(ret, n=5, align = 'right', fill=NA))
```